# Implementing Dictionary interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface

This is the IEnumerable interface in which adding some words and returning in last two methods.

The idea here is that you have a Dicitionary that will associate each word to a List of words that are synonyms. The AddSynonyms method will take an enumeration of synonyms and begin by creating a list of unique words, in case there are any duplicates. It then goes through each word and checks to see if it has already been added. If it has then it goes through all the synonyms of that word (the words list minus the word) and checks to see if they are in the List associated with that word. If not the synonym is added to the list. If the word is not already in the Dicitionary then it is added along with a List of it's synonyms (again the words list minus the word).

The GetSynonymns method then just returns the List that is associated with the given word. If the word is not in the Thesaurus then an empty enumeration is returned (you could change that to throw an exception if so desired).

The GetWords method simply returns all the keys of the Dicitionary which will be every word that was added.

```
summary>
/// Represents a thesaurus.
/// </summary>
public interface IThesaurus
{
/// <summary>
/// Adds the given synonyms to the thesaurus
/// </summary>
/// <param name="synonyms">The synonyms to add.</param>
void AddSynonyms(IEnumerable<string> synonyms);

/// <summary>
/// Gets the synonyms for a given word.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="word">The word the synonyms of which to get.</param>
/// <returns>A <see cref="string"/> with all synonyms for the given word.</returns>
IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word);

/// <summary>
/// Gets all words from the thesaurus.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerable<string>"/> containing
/// all the words in the thesaurus.</returns>
IEnumerable<string> GetWords();
```

}
}

This is how far I have gotten, but  seem stuck at this. The program won't compile properly. I'm unable to call my method with the obj.GetSynonyms();. Ath the bottom of my public thesaurus class public IEnumerable GetWords() { return lookup.Keys(); } } Doesn't work I just can't understand why it will not work. I can't really spot the problem with the code.

```
   namespace Thesaurus
 {
    public interface IThesaurus
    {
        IEnumerable<string> AddSynonyms();
        IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word);

        IEnumerable<string> GetWords();
}


public class Thesaurus : IThesaurus
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> lookup =
        new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public IEnumerable<string> AddSynonyms() //public void AddSynonyms(IEnumerable<string> synonyms)
    {
        var words = AddSynonyms.Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            var currentWordSynonyms = words.Where(s => s == word);
            if (lookup.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                foreach (var synonym in currentWordSynonyms)
                {
                    if (!lookup[word].Contains(synonym))
                        lookup[word].Add(synonym);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lookup.Add(word.currentWordSynonyms);
            }

        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word)
    {
        if (lookup.ContainsKey(word))
            return lookup[word];
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        // Or throw an exception.
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetWords()
    {
        return lookup.Keys();
    }
}

class MainClass
{

    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare an interface instance.
        IThesaurus obj = new Thesaurus();


        // Call the member.
        obj.AddSynonyms();
        obj.GetSynonyms();
        obj.GetWords();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Not obvious.

Comment: @jdweng

The program won't compile properly. 

I'm unable to call my method with the  obj.GetSynonyms();.

Ath the bottom of my public thesaurus class
 public IEnumerable<string> GetWords()
    {
        return lookup.Keys();
    }
}

Doesn't work 

I just can't understand why it will not work. I can't really spot the problem with the code.

Comment: Probably a good idea to add the info from your comment to your question text.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and edit your question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @garfbradaz I have read the guide, anything in particular there I should change? Is it the title? My problem? I'm not sure what else I can do to improve the question asking. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Got compiler errors out :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Thesaurus
{


    class MainClass
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Declare an interface instance.
            IThesaurus obj = new Thesaurus();
            List<string> words = new List<string>();

            // Call the member.
            obj.AddSynonyms(words);
            obj.GetSynonyms(words[0]);
            obj.GetWords();
        }
    }
    //<summary>
    /// Represents a thesaurus.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IThesaurus
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the given synonyms to the thesaurus
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="synonyms">The synonyms to add.</param>
        void AddSynonyms(IEnumerable<string> synonyms);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the synonyms for a given word.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="word">The word the synonyms of which to get.</param>
        /// <returns>A <see cref="string"/> with all synonyms for the given word.</returns>
        IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all words from the thesaurus.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerable<string>"/> containing
        /// all the words in the thesaurus.</returns>
        IEnumerable<string> GetWords();
    }

    public class Thesaurus : IThesaurus
    {
        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> lookup =
            new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();



        public void AddSynonyms(IEnumerable<string> allWords) //public void AddSynonyms(IEnumerable<string> synonyms)
        {
            var words = allWords.Distinct().ToList();
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                var currentWordSynonyms = words.Where(s => s == word);
                if (lookup.ContainsKey(word))
                {
                    foreach (var synonym in currentWordSynonyms)
                    {
                        if (!lookup[word].Contains(synonym))
                            lookup[word].Add(synonym);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    List<string> newSynonyms =  new List<string>();
                    newSynonyms.AddRange(currentWordSynonyms);
                    lookup.Add(word, newSynonyms);
                }

            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word)
        {
            if (lookup.ContainsKey(word))
                return lookup[word];
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            // Or throw an exception.
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetWords()
        {
            return lookup.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: When attempting to compile I get an out of range exception when obj.GetSynonyms(words[0]); is called.Except that it works.

Comment: Do you have : using System.Collections.  It is not usually a default when a new project is created.

Comment: Did you add words to the list?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but how do I add words to the list?

Comment: Its your project.  What are your inputs?

Comment: How about "one", "two", "three"? But where am I supposed to write it in order to enter it in the list? Sorry for these basic questions, I'm a bit over my head but I think I will really benefit from understanding this in the end. 

When attempting to run I just get 
"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'"

Comment: When fixed the errors I put into main() words[0] just to get rid of the compiler errors. GetSynonyms required a string input.  I assumed you were going to modify code when you imported real data.  You can read from a file or simply do this : List<string> words = new List<string>(){"one","two","three"};

Comment: Ah of course. That was obvious now that you write it. You just replace  List<string> words = new List<string>(); with it, right? Seem to be working. 

The next step is to build an interface in WPF, but I'm pretty clueless where to begin. Do you have any link or anything? Else I'm probably satisifed with this. 

Thanks a lot, you really helped me understand.

Comment: Try a google search for : codeproject C# wpf application